# Run geant 4 example with java

Tags: java, c++

I'm using Ubuntu and I have installed geant 4 and compiled some of its examples.

Is there any way that I can run these example with java (geant 4 and its examples are coded with C++).

Comment: What's going wrong actually? What do you mean _"run with java"_? Do you want to port from c++ code to java? That's a way to broad question then.

Comment: Better design a compiler for converting c++ code to java .